# How do I show time and date beneath a box, like facebook or worpress posts?

Tags: php, html, css

How do we display time and date beneath a post or most `right-bottom` of a box like facebook or wordpress?
like I have code here.

```
 <html>
 <body>

  <div style="height:30px; width:500px; color:gray; background-color: #ffffff">
   <p>hello, welcome to the first post of my blog!</p>
   <?php echo $now->format("m-d-Y H:i:s.u");  ?> 

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I display time and date beneath or most `bottom-right` of this `div` here?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your php tag with this div
`<div align="right" ><?php echo $now->format("m-d-Y H:i:s.u");  ?>
</div>`

Comment: Thank you for your response, with what attribute? don't get it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i thought there would be some special attribute or some thing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Laa.jpg)

you can insert the date format as you like

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought there would be some magic attribute for that thank you..

Comment: <span style="float:right"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format'));?></span>